# Terminator? Nah

Tags: riddle, knowledge, wordplay, lateral-thinking

> Resonate me to leave me whole.
>
> Tamper with me to leave me good.
>
> Gather me to leave me alone.
>
> Trim me to leave me empty.

What would happen if you retrieve me?

Subtle Hint:

> You can see me shrinking as you read this riddle line-by-line.

Moderate Hint:

> Trimming me is very different from the other actions mentioned.

Decisive Hint:

> Resonate him to leave him alone.
>  Tamper with him to leave him alone.
>  Gather him to leave him alone.
>  Trim him to leave him alone.

Very Decisive Hint:

> Bring your thesaurus for the action of each line.

Very² Decisive Hint:

> He is the terminator.

Comment: Does [tag:wordplay] fully apply here or is this more of a [tag:riddle] than [tag:wordplay]? Also, it looks like [tag:word] would apply to the final answer?

Comment: @Tacoタコス Yes, it's definitely a wordplay, but no, the "word" tag wouldn't apply.

Comment: V xrrc pbzvat onpx gb bar friragu, ohg gur pnfr sbe vg frrzf jrnx...

Answer (score 2):

**What would happen if you retrieve me?**

> I answer the phone because you called me.

Partial answer based on:

> Synonyms..?

Terminator? Nah

> Nah suggests using the opposite of terminator, which would be an initiator (of the phone call).

Resonate me to leave me whole.

> "Call" me to "allow" me "to be sound" as in a ringing telephone.

Tamper with me to leave me good.

> All I've got for this is "good" may be "fine", as in a financial penalty?

Gather me to leave me alone.

> All I've got for this is "gather" may be "collect", as in a collect call?

Trim me to leave me empty.

> All I've got for this is that Trim phones were very popular in the 80's and "empty" may be "free", as in a toll-free call?

Comment: You got that rot13(flabalzf) is the wordplay.

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

I think it might be

> a progression of anagrams and altering the letters of the title.

Gather me to leave me alone.

> I'm guessing the word for this step is "hermit" which would be created by gathering the h from "nah" and ermit from "terminator".  Which may mean those are the letters left after the previous steps and what is left to work with for step 4.

Also:

> Step 4 says to "trim", the letters of which are contained in hermit, but trimming "trim" leaves he or eh, so not sure.

Maybe that will help or maybe I'm totally off base!

Comment: Well, this was a different type of wordplay.